# Get content of the dynamically created element using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Using server side process I have created my table and I am loading some data in a  element like bellow

I want the content of class more

element, I tried using ready, load but I am getting undefined when alert is made so please someone help me

My Whole code is here

```
    <div  class="container margin_120" id="form1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div id="tools">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <h4 class="inner margin_5_tb"><i class=""></i>View Counts of Students Needing Financial Assistance<button type="button" id="button1" style="border:none;background-Color:#EAECEE; float: right;font-size:12px" ><u>Hide</u></button></h4>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                </div><!--/tools -->
                <div class="form-group" id="countTableDes">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="loan_data">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Student Photo</th>
                                <th>some data</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var dataTable = $('#loan_data').DataTable({  
            "processing":true,  
            "serverSide":true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "order":[],  
            "ajax":{  
                   url:'<?php echo site_url("home/getLoans"); ?>',
                   type:"POST"  
            },  

            "columns":[
                {   'data' : 'stu_firstName' },
                {   'data' : 'id',
                    'render':function(id,data,row){
                            if(row.stu_passportPhoto && row.stu_passportPhoto!=null){
                            return '<p class="more"><b>About me</b> <br/>'+row.stu_aboutStudent+'</p>';
                                }
                    }
                },
                {
                    'data' : 'stu_somedata'
                },
            ]       
        });
 //Here I want to get each more class content.
        $(document).find(".more").each(function(){
            var content = $(this).text();
            alert(content); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: If you watch the table using the browser inspector tool, do you see that `p.more` elements in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: Is the `.DataTable()` call inside of the `$(document).ready()` function and is executed before your `p.more` selection?

Comment: Yes that is the flow only

Comment: Dynamically created elements can't be called by class name directly some time. You have to access them through root. So instead of $(".more") write $(document).find(".more").each.

Comment: @Dushant Singh, I tried your solution but it is not entered the each loop.. I mean it is not alerted anything.

Comment: @Mahantesh please check length of elements in console. Check they are accessible directly or not. Use .length()  and check out-put

Comment: @Dushant Singh, I don't know how to do this

Comment: can you show us your complete  `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: @Makarand Patil, Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the elements with the class "more" are created dynamically by the DataTable, you have to wait until the table or at least the row has been drawn completely. In order to do so, you have to hook into one of the available callbacks that DataTables offers:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Which one exactly depends on your needs, presumably `drawCallback` should work for your case, or you could also use `createdRow` for each row separately.

This is the example snippet from the docs, adapted to illustrate your case:

```
$('#loan_data').dataTable( {
    // rest of your options goes here...
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        // you'll want to select only inside your table,
        // not the whole document, for performance reasons:
        $('#loan_data').find(".more").each(function(){
            var content = $(this).text();
            alert(content); 
        });
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the way datatable is rendered and how column:render is executed,

Worst case scenario is to use a mutator, or an event listener

such as `Arrive.js`

here is the link,

https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/blob/master/src/arrive.js

It will listen to newly created elements and you can run something inside its function,

Do something like this,

```
$(document).arrive(".more", function() {
    // 'this' refers to the newly created element
    var content = $(this).text();
    alert(content);  /* do something */
});
```